# CentOS 7 need an usb device to boot

Tags: centos, usb, kickstart

I have to install CentOS 7.3 on multiple computers with some packages and some configuration, so I opted for a kickstart installation.
Theses computers doesn't have any CD player so I used Rufus software and an USB key.

I made an installation that works, but I have to put more RPM in my kickstart installation so I rebuilded my custom iso, putted this on another USB key (same model...), but when my installation is finished I can't boot on my hard drive, I only have a black screen with a flashing underscore (where i can't write anything or switch tty) instead of the prompt for login/password. The mystery is when I plug my usb key in the computer, it boot normally...

Here is my `ks.cfg` (sometimes my usb is recognized as `sda1` and sometimes `sdb1`):

```
# Use USB installation media  
harddrive --partition=sdb1 --dir=/  
# Auto part
clearpart --all --initlabel  
bootloader --location=mbr  
autopart --type=lvm  
zerombr  
# No X Window + text install  
text  
skipx
```

EDIT : I still have this problem... But it works fine if I use my usb key that is recognized as `sdb1` (which I would call n°1, and the other n°2), even if I don't use the autopart.

Comment: What do the console messages say (CTRL+ALT+F1) ?

Comment: When I boot with the usb key plugged in ?
(I have to rebuild my usb key and re-install the OS because I just installed with the old usb key to be sure it works fine with it, then I will post the answer)

Comment: If I do CTRL+ALT+F1 after my computer booted and after I logged in, it doesn't do any action (just try to switch to tty1 I think but it's where I already are).  

Maybe you want that I try this when I'm installing the OS ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found a solution !

I use a script that detect the bigger SSD (my hard drive) and the bigger hdd (my usb key), then I use my variables to designate the installation target and the installation source with
`bootloader --boot-drive=$BIGGER_SSD`
`harddrive --partition=${BIGGER_HDD}1 --dir=/`